# Unable to use references in ToC names with minitoc

Tags: table-of-contents, minitoc

I'm trying to customize `minitoc`-generated ToCs by changing their titles, in order not to have way too much 'Contents' page around my book.

However, when I try to use `\mtcsettitle` using references, the weirdest errors occur; in particular, I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```latex
\mtcsettitle{parttoc}{\ref{somepartref} -- \nameref{somepartref}}
```

Here comes an MWE where at least the `\ref` command is properly accepted, despite throwing errors anyway:

```latex
% !TEX program = lualatex
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX spellcheck = en_GB
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, titlepage, oneside]{book}

\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{minitoc}

\begin{document}
  \selectlanguage{british}

  \frontmatter

  \mtcaddchapter[\contentsname]
  \dominitoc
  \doparttoc
  \mtcsetdepth{parttoc}{0}
  \noptcrule
  \tableofcontents
  \clearpage

  \mtcaddchapter[\listfigurename]
  \listoffigures
  \clearpage

  \mainmatter
  \part{First part}
  \label{part:first}
  \mtcsettitle{parttoc}{\ref{part:first} -- \nameref{part:first}}
  \parttoc
  \chapter{Introduction}
  \minitoc
  \mtcskip

  This is some sort of joke introduction, for demo purposes only.
  \begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \caption{This is a fake image}
    \label{fig:fakeimage}
  \end{figure}

  \chapter{Conclusion}
  \minitoc
  \mtcskip
  Is this the real life? Or is this fantasy?

  \section{Look, I'm a section too!}
  \ldots

\end{document}
```

Errors are something like this:

```
...
! Undefined control sequence.
\ptctitle ->\ref {part:first} -- \nameref 
                                          {part:first}
l.31   \chapter
             {Introduction}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\ptctitle ->\ref {part:first} -- \nameref 
                                          {part:first}
l.31   \chapter
             {Introduction}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


\openout3 = fake.mtc
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 31.
<inserted text> 
\fi 
l.31   \chapter
             {Introduction}
A forbidden control sequence occurred in skipped text.
This kind of error happens when you say `\if...' and forget
the matching `\fi'. I've inserted a `\fi'; this might work.

! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 31.
<inserted text> 
\fi 
l.31   \chapter
             {Introduction}
A forbidden control sequence occurred in skipped text.
This kind of error happens when you say `\if...' and forget
the matching `\fi'. I've inserted a `\fi'; this might work.

Runaway text?
\protect \let 
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning text of \write.
<inserted text> 
}
l.31   \chapter
             {Introduction}
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.

! Text line contains an invalid character.
<read 1> \protect \let  
                  
l.31   \chapter
             {Introduction}
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.


\openout3 = fake.mtc
! Undefined control sequence.
\ptctitle ->\ref {part:first} -- \nameref 
                                          {part:first}
l.31   \chapter
             {Introduction}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
...
```

So,I'm not sure whether I cannot in fact use references within `\mtcsettitle` command or I'm missing some bigger picture.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Have you tried adding `\protect` before `\ref` and `\nameref` in the argument of `\mtcsettitle`?

Comment: Does it work in MWE? 'Cause it doesn't in my document.

Comment: Admittedly, I didn't test with the MWE.  This was a guess.  Early expansion of `\ref` and similar commands is a very frequent source of this kind of failure in "indirect" environments, where an argument is passed through for later processing, e.g., into an `.aux` file.  If the error is triggered from an `.aux` file entry, you need to delete the existing one before trying again.  (I'm not a user of either `minitoc` or lualatex.)

Comment: I'll try to delete the `.aux` file then.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't do the trick.

Comment: Okay.  Thanks for the feedback.  This will need to be addressed by someone more familiar with `minitoc`.